# why is my class getting the wrong values?

Tags: python, pygame

I recently started exploring classes and I have made my first class (sort of) but it  doesn't seem to be working.  I have code creating the class and function, then takes the values and blits an image to certain coordinates.  for some reason It takes the values from inside the class instead of what I told it to have.  I am new to classes so I'm not sure what to do, please help, thanks!

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
Screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 400))

TC = pygame.image.load("TC.png").convert_alpha()
ANUM = 0


class MTC() :
  def __init__(self,) :
    self.Tx = 0
    self.Ty = 0
    
    Screen.blit(TC,(self.Tx,self.Ty))


TMTC = MTC()
TMTC.Tx = 800
TMTC.Ty = 800



while True:
  for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
    

  
  pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Because you only change the values *after* you call `__init__()`

Comment: Right.  Think about the order of operations.  You call `MTC()`, which creates an object and calls `__init__`.  That assigns 0 to `Tx` and `Ty`, and then calls blit with those values.  When that returns, THEN you change `Tx` and `Ty, but the object has already been displayed.  You need to pass x and y to the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `Screen.blit` in the class constructor which is executed when your class is instantiated (`TMTC = MTC()`).

You are then setting the tx and ty after `Screen.blit` has already run

Answer (score 2):

The image is `blit` in the constructor. At this point the coordinates are not yet changed. You have add a method that `blit`s the object:

```py
class MTC() :
    def __init__(self,) :
        self.Tx = 0
        self.Ty = 0

    def dra():
        Screen.blit(TC,(self.Tx,self.Ty))
```

Call the `draw` method in the application loop:

```py
TMTC = MTC()
TMTC.Tx = 800
TMTC.Ty = 800

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
    
      Screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
      TMTC.draw()
      pygame.display.update()
```